# Выбор полигона под полигоном API Яндекс.Карт

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

В своем проекте использую API Яндекс.Карт, в частности отрисовываются объекты полигонами по имеющимся в базе координатам. Временами бывает так, что один полигон полностью перекрывает другой. Предположим, что перекрывающий слой больше нижележащего, потому невозможно кликнуть на нижележащий полигон и увидеть информацию в балуне. Каким образом я могу выбрать нижележащий слой? Вопрос именно в способе взаимодействия для конечного пользователя. Быть может есть какой-то атрибут для полигонов, который позволит переключаться между наложением слоев друг на друга? Заранее спасибо!

[image: Наложение полигонов]

Answer (score 1):

Для геообъектов можно [настроить `zIndex`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Polygon-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.zIndex). Как именно реализовать UX уже зависит только от вашего дизайна: например, можно слушать событие клика по полигону и показывать кастомный диалог для выбора одной из пересекающихся фигур, или можно заранее класть выше многоугольник с меньшей площадью.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где бы я мог ознакомиться с практическим примером реализации подобного? Куда копать, иными словами. Дело в том, что в JS полный профан и все что удалось наклепать - по мануалам из API. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это просто опция, которую надо указать в коде геообъекта, например, через метод геообъекта `options.set("zIndex", 1000)` Вся остальная логика для решения задачи не связана с API и, боюсь, без знания js будет сложновато.